# Replace preg_replace to preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, preg-replace

Can someone please help me with converting code

`$file = preg_replace('~&#([0-9]+);~e', 'chr("\\1")', $file);`

to use `preg_replace_callback` instead of it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`$file = preg_replace_callback('~&#([0-9]+);~', function($m) { return chr($m[1]); }, $file);`

If you are on a version of php that doesn't support anonymous functions, you can do this instead:

```
function myfunction($m) { return chr($m[1]); }
$file = preg_replace_callback('~&#([0-9]+);~', 'myfunction', $file);
```

Comment: Oh this is sure the way to go, but `preg_replace` should be `preg_replace_callback` shouldn't it :)

Comment: @Jonny5 I'm not sure what you mean.. this is what the OP asked for:  convert `preg_replace` to `preg_replace_callback`

Comment: @CrayonViolent: he means you have made a typo, you have written `preg_replace` instead of `preg_replace_callback`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be something like this:

```
$file = preg_replace_callback(
           '~&#([0-9]+);~',
           function ($matches) {
              // action
           },
           $file
);
```

PS. Without e modificator.